# Onsen ui:Disable device backbutton in android didnt work

Tags: android, cordova, onsen-ui

I am developing an android application using Cordova and Onsenui, in whic i want to disable the android back button handler.
I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211418/how-to-disable-android-back-button-handler-in-onsen-ui-phonegap) 
answer ,but didnt work for me

Here is my code its placed on top of my `app.js` file

```
ons.ready(function() {
  ons.disableDeviceBackButtonHandler();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you are using `<ons-navigator var="myNavigator"></ons-navigator>`, have you already tried something like this?

```
// To disable a navigator back button handler
myNavigator.getDeviceBackButtonHandler().disable();
```

You should also not forget to add `cordova.js` reference to your index page. You don't need to paste the file, it will be generated automatically every time you deploy a Cordova app.

```
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

If you don't add it, it will not be possible to manipulate the BackButton behavior.

Default behavior:

- Main page: closes the app.
- Other pages: goes back.

Disabling the handler, the app will be closed every time you press the button, regardless the page.

Comment: let me try your answer

Comment: i am using `ons-navigator` but the solution is didn't work

Comment: maybe there is a bug, I'll investigate

Comment: @shammon I just updated my answer, have you added `cordova.js` reference?

Comment: I've added,let me check again

Comment: sure, it should work with your code, I just tested it, I also added an explanation of the behavior

Comment: I've disable the onsenui script and added the cordova backubutton event handler Its worked,but the onsenui backbutton handler didn't work.

Comment: you haven't added any code about it, you just asked about the deviceBackButton

Comment: Double cheked the things you have spefied in the answer,

Comment: Probably there is a little bit of confusion. My code was about the navigator back button, not onsen backbutton. The navigator backbutton is always the cordova back button, but it's behavior is enabled only when there is a navigator. Maybe you are talking about `ons-back-button`, with is a `ons-toolbar` element. It's behavior cannot be changed.